# What's the best practice to deploy React app to GCP App Engine

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, deployment

There's like a milion articles on the internet about React app deployment to GCP App Engine, but I've been unable to find an answer to this:

A) Should you really build on localhost and then **only deploy the `dist`** (or `build`) folder? (Like most articles and YouTube tutorials suggest?)

B) Or should you use **App Engine to do the build** for you? I.e., should you exclude the `dist` folder, upload all the artifacts, and let App Engine run the `build` script from your package.json?

What would be the best practice and why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Should you really build on localhost and then only deploy the `dist` (or `build`) folder? (Like most articles and YouTube tutorials suggest?)

Building/testing on localhost is optional but this is a best practice to ensure that your service would run without any issues before deploying to Google App Engine. Once you've included all the necessary requirements for your service (`package.json`, `PORT`, `app.yaml`, dependencies, etc.), you may either test it first or deploy your web service immediately. You may check this documentation on [writing your web service with node.js](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/writing-web-service) for your reference.

> 2. Should you use App Engine to do the build for you? I.e., should you exclude the `dist` folder, upload all the artifacts, and let App Engine run the `build` script from your package.json?

You have the freedom to set up your App Engine service. As previously mentioned, once you've included all the necessary requirements for your service (`package.json`, `PORT`, `app.yaml`, dependencies, etc.), you can deploy your service by testing it on localhost or deploying it immediately. Also, the correct way to deploy Google App Engine is:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

The first thing that you need to do is selecting either App Engine Standard or Flexible.

Below are some of the references that I personally use to deploy Google App Engine for node/react:

- [Node.js on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/nodejs)
- [Building a Node.js app on App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app)
- [Setting up your development environment (standard)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/setting-up-environment?tab=node.js)
- [The Node.js runtime (flexible)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime)
- [Create a Node.js app in the App Engine flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/create-app)
- [Setting up your development environment (flexible)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/setting-up-environment?tab=node.js)
- [How to deploy React application to Google Cloud (App Engine)?](https://www.codingdeft.com/posts/react-deploy-google-cloud-app-engine/)
- [5 Step Guide To Deploy Your React App On Google’s App Engine](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/quickly-deploy-your-react-app-on-googles-app-engine-6bb97480cc9c)